# C# - Append an XElement array to XElement

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq, xelement

I have a c# application, where I'm doing a data compare of two xml files inside a method called *RevisionTree*. I return a list of elements(XElement) from this method. From the *BuildXml* method, call that method and save the list as *tree*. Next I create an xml *root* XElement. I then loop over each element from tree and add specified descendants (status, msg, date) to the *root* element, each one of these are XElement.  So i should see an xml doument with *root*, then a list of repeating xml. **However, when i try to save the to the writer i get the following error.**

Error

```
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in System.Private.Xml.dll
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Private.Xml.dll
Token StartDocument in state Document would result in an invalid XML document.
```

Code

```
    {
        IEnumerable<XElement>
        var tree = RevisionTree("C:\\Users\\Owner\\source\\repos\\SvnCore\\SvnCore\\old_logs.xml", "C:\\Users\\Owner\\source\\repos\\SvnCore\\SvnCore\\new_logs.xml");

        using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create("C:\\Users\\Owner\\source\\repos\\SvnCore\\SvnCore\\Temp.xml", xmlSettings))
        {
            writer.WriteStartDocument();
            var root = new XElement("root");
            foreach (var node in tree)
            {
                root.Add(new XElement("id", node.FirstAttribute));
                root.Add(node.Descendants("status").FirstOrDefault());
                root.Add(node.Descendants("msg").FirstOrDefault());
                root.Add(node.Descendants("date").FirstOrDefault());
            }
            root.Save(writer); 
            writer.WriteEndElement();
            writer.WriteEndDocument();
        }
        return true; 
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Try `root.WriteTo(writer)`. (Alternatively, leave out your manual writing of the document/element nodes -- `Save` should already take care of it, which is why you're getting the error.)

Comment: @JeroenMostert, you are correct. Please create an answer, ( maybe elaborate why i should not be using save ?), ill give mark it as the correct solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`XElement.Save` produces an entire document on its own -- you need `XElement.WriteTo`, which does not. So either (simplified):

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
using (var sw = new StringWriter(sb))
using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(sw)) {
    var root = new XElement("root");
    root.Add(new XElement("id", "1"));
    root.Save(writer);  // no DocumentStart, no ElementStart
}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?><root><id>1</id></root>
```

or (if you wanted to write multiple elements, or for some other reason want to control the document node yourself):

```
using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(sw)) {
    writer.WriteStartDocument();
    writer.WriteStartElement("root");
    var notRoot = new XElement("notRoot");
    notRoot.Add(new XElement("id", "1"));
    notRoot.WriteTo(writer); 
    notRoot.WriteTo(writer);
}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?><root><notRoot><id>1</id></notRoot><notRoot><id>1</id></notRoot></root>
```

Note that I'm omitting the `End` calls, since the `XmlWriter` will take care of that implicitly.

If you aren't doing anything interesting with the `xmlSettings`, the whole thing is even simpler since `XElement.Save` has an overload that accepts a file name directly, so you don't need an `XmlWriter` at all.